# How to check if a file is in a specific folder?

Tags: python, file, if-statement, python-os

I have the following structure:

```
root
   |_ Audi
         |_file1.txt
         |_file2.txt

   |_ Mercedes
         |_file1.txt
         |_file2.txt
```

I want to create a function that checks wether a file is in `Audi` or `Mercedes`.

1. If the files are in `Audi' process.....
2. If the files are in `Mercedes` process..

This is my code:

```
root = r'C:\data\desktop\my_folder\my_cars'

def move_to_db (path):
    ls_mts_raw = [] 
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            file_path = os.path.join(path, file)

move_to_db(root)
```

This is what I have untill now but I got stuck.....

Comment: You want to process file regarding its parent folder?

Comment: @MetallimaX Yes correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code, you will obtain a dict with the brands as keys and a list of file names as values.

```py
import glob

from pathlib import Path

files = glob.glob(r"./root/*/*.txt") # You can use os.path.join() here
files_by_brand = {}

for file in files:
    path = Path(file)
    brand_name = path.parent.name
    file_name = path.resolve().as_posix()
    file_list = files_by_brand.setdefault(brand_name, [])
    file_list.append(file_name)

print(files_by_brand)
```

Comment: if I print `files_by_brand` I reiceive the following: `{'my_folders': ['C:/data/FF/Desktop/my_folders/my_cars']}`. Thats not the suposed answer I guess.

Comment: I've edited the code because I changed the content of the glob which had sense in my env with something neutral ... but too much neutral that made no sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

@Metallimax.

So I've did this now:

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path

path_root = r'c:\data\FF\Desktop\my_folders\my_cars'

files = glob.glob(path_root) # You can use os.path.join() here
files_by_brand = {}

for file in files:
    path = Path(file)
    brand_name = path.parent.name
    file_name = path.resolve().as_posix()
    file_list = files_by_brand.setdefault(brand_name, [])
    file_list.append(file_name)

print(files_by_brand)
```

I receieved this:

```
In [37]:runfile('c:/data/FF/Desktop/Python/the_cars.py', wdir='c:/data/FF/Desktop/Python')

{'my_folders': ['C:/data/FF/Desktop/my_folders/my_cars']}
```

Comment: You have to had `r"\*\*.txt"` at the end of `path_root` in your `glob()` call.

Comment: @MetallimaX I dont understand you. What do you mean?

Comment: `glob()` is retrieving some filenames based on a pattern. In your example you mentionned a brand level (Audi, Mercedes) followed by `.txt` files. You have to target those `.txt` files  with the glob pattern. And the code is computing the brand name from the parent folder of the `.txt` files and sort them by this brand. If your glob pattern is not aiming the right files of course the rest of the process is wrong.

Comment: Got it and fixed it!. Would appreciate it if you could give me an UP for my question